# download the lightning component or deploy to other servers(different salesforce accounts)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment, ide

Is there any possibility to **download the lightning components**?
Similar to an option to download apex class?
or Is there any IDE that supports Lightning Components?
Any option **deploy to other servers**(different salesforce accounts) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple way.

Use atom tool https://atom.io/ for dowloding your packages.

Steps to install mavensmate plugin in ATOM tool. https://atom.io/packages/mavensmate-atom
and open org in **atom** tool and save your workspace.

now open another org. In second org workspacae copy all the lightning artifact from first org and deploy everything.

The easiest way. Create unmanage package add your components and install into target org.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools available to do that.

- [Eclipse SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) to download your Lightning component and you can use the same to deploy to any other Salesforce org.
- [Mavensmate](http://mavensmate.com) can also be used to deploy
- if you are familiar with force.com migration tool you can use that as well.

**Eclipse version:**

Make sure you are using apex API version 33.0

- Open Eclipse package.xml
- Use following package.xml code

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

  <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
  </types>
  <version>33.0</version>
  </Package>
  ```
- Right click on your Project Force.com -> Refresh from server.

Comment: @user26624 answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think all the major ides now support lightning components. The metadata and tooling API doesn't work quite as good as for Apex classes but they do work somehow.

For me, I am using HaoIde which might not be a major choice here: https://github.com/xjsender/haoide . It does support lightning component and deploying to other server directly. I bet Mavensmate and Eclipse force.ide support lightning components, too. MavensMate doesn't support direct deploying to other server so you will have to copy/paste. Eclipse I am not quite sure.

Comment: I am sure about eclipse,I use that to deploy lightning component :)

Answer (score 1):

All of the tools mentioned in the other answers should work. When retrieving/deploying, the metadata that you are looking for is named `AuraDefinitionBundle`. Note that it doesn't have "Lightning" in the name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your support, sorry i don't have enough reputations to add comments, so consolidating here

Finally

```
 <types>   
    <members>*</members>
    <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
 </types>
```

inclusion in the property file for any IDE is the solution.

@Himanshu: thanks.. your answer really worked for eclipse IDE.

@Lance Shi : your link also worked with little difficulty to configure the HAOIDE in sublime https://github.com/xjsender/haoide .

@Ratan :Un-managed packages really good , but i made mistakes in the intial for configuring IDE's. IN atom i am facing instalation issues.

@martin: Actually your answer is the exact answer , since this was given by in high-level ,my bad i did not understand in the first instance ...