# Open/create lightning component in Force.com IDE

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com-ide

I'm relatively new to Salesforce and have gone through a tutorial creating a lightning component, using the web based developer console.

I would like to open the component with the Force.com IDE that I just downloaded and setup.  If I cannot open the existing code, creating new code is OK.

However I can't see any way to open existing code, or create a lightning .cmp file.

[image: force.com ide new menu]

How do I open an existing project or create a new lightning component project?

Comment: First go to **New** > **Force.com Project** From there you should be able to select the lightning components. If you want to start with a package.xml file for the retrieval, you should check out this [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/download-the-lightning-component-or-deploy-to-other-serversdifferent-salesforce/100536#100536)

Comment: @martin Thanks, so the 'New' menu isn't going to overwrite my online code, just open it?

Comment: Don't worry, each project that you create will store a new local copy of your metadata. Changes won't be made in Salesforce itself unless you choose to sync with server.

Comment: Yes, I just installed the latest version - Neon, and updated jre to v8, and lightning plug, but I met the same issue. I can now open an existing Aura file but can`t create a lightning bundler on IDE.   Does your ide can create it now?

Comment: @Leisure sorry I don't know about the latest version, it worked when I was doing it with the old version.  You can always create lightning components online, and open them with the IDE I would think.

Comment: Thanks, I`ve already resolved this issue via re-building a new empty workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use https://atom.io/ IDE

Steps to install mavensmate plugin in ATOM tool. https://atom.io/packages/mavensmate-atom and open org in atom tool and save your workspace.

Yes As suggested by @Martin For eclipse

Open your project in eclipse. In your project open package.xml

You can add using below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

Save file and take refresh from server. You can see **aura** folder is created with all lightning component.

Thanks to @martin

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked but what wasn't clear (for others), is you right click on the package->Force.com->Refresh from server

Comment: For others embarking on this - Force.com IDE just butchered my files on the server because of 'an error' during synchronization.  Frankly the point of using Force.com IDE was for debugging APEX but now I find I cannot do that without paying extra.  So really all the IDE does is provide local backup, but it seems dubious at that job too....

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    
        *
        AuraDefinitionBundle
    
    35.0