# Can't create Lightning Components via Eclipse (beta)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, eclipse, force.com-ide

I have tried to install Force.com IDE in Eclipse and also download the feature to be able to work with [Lightning Components in Eclipse](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/wiki/Downloading-the-Beta-Version-of-the-Force.com-IDE). However I was not able to make it work.

I have also asked for it on Developer Forums, so please, take a look at this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000XgHoQAK) where I explain better the use case.

I have also see [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101744/open-create-lightning-component-in-force-com-ide) here, but I would like not to use ATOM.

Really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: In Eclipse, in `Force.com > Project properties`, did you concatenate your password and the Salesforce token ?

Comment: Yes, I did and also reset the token just in case.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Mars 4.5.2